# c++ Custom type array initialiazion

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have:

```
    Class SomeClass{
    private:
        int a;
        char* name;
    public:
        SomeClass(int a = 0, char* n = "---"){
           ...
        }
    };

    Class OtherClass{
    private:
    SomeClass anArray[100];
    int counter;
    ...
    public:
        ...
    };
```

How do I initialize the array of type SomeClass? As far as I know, when you have a private member that belongs to a user defined class, to initialize it you should include it in the constructor

```
    OtherClass(...):SomeClass(...){
       ...
    }
```

However, the contents of the array are left for the user to enter, so they are much too unpredictable, and manually entering default values for each field is obviously out of the question.

Comment: Did you consider putting your inconvenient default values in a constructor for `SomeClass` and let the array construction just have its way with that?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that SomeClass has a default constructor. What I'm curious about is what the exact code is to simply let it call the SomeClass def. constructor a hundred times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your `SomeClass` has a default constructor, you don't need to anything: the default constructor will be call for each if the elements. You want to mention it explicitly can use

```
OtherClass::OtherClass()
    : anArray() {
}
```

If you want to initialize the sequence of elements with an explicit constructor call with typing it out, you can use a delegating constructor taking a suitably size `std::index_sequence<...>` and use aggregate initialization of the elements. Here is a complete example of how that would look like:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int value;
    S(int value): value(value) {}
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, S const& s) {
    return out << s.value;
}

template <typename S, typename T, std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::size_t static_size(T (S::*)[Size]) {
    return Size;
}

class T {
    S array[100];
    template <std::size_t... I>
    T(std::index_sequence<I...>): array{ S(I)... } {}
public:
    T(): T(std::make_index_sequence<static_size(&T::array)>()) {}
    S const* begin() const { return std::begin(array); }
    S const* end() const   { return std::end(array); }
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    std::copy(t.begin(), t.end(), std::ostream_iterator<S>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: The first block works perfectly. Unfortunately, I'm not yet that deep into c++ to fully understand the second code sample. I do have another question though, if SomeClass didn't have a default constructor, could have I gotten away with simply providing the required data on the spot. OtherClass():anArray(arg1, arg2, arg3){...}

Comment: @AericWintershard: well, that is kind of what the second example does :) You could use aggregate initialization but you'll need to mention each element. A manual version of an array of, say, two elements would look like this: `OtherClass::OtherClass(): anArray{ SomeClass(1, "one"), SomeClass(2, "two") } {}`. The variadic argument simply generates a sequence of integers and expanding it results in a generated version of the elements. If the elements take other arguments, e.g., the 3 arguments, you could fudge it by expanding e.g. `(I, SomeClass(arg1, arg2, arg3))...`.